# Clipboard copy-paste of an object between two applications

Tags: vb.net, casting, clipboard

I tried to use copy-paste of an object between two application and got an error 
" System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to type 'howto_net_clipboard_object.Employee'.'" , so I took the sample from http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_clipboard_object.html and started to experiment.
The object to copy is

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class Employee
    Public FirstName As String
    Public LastName As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal first_name As String, ByVal last_name As String)
        FirstName = first_name
        LastName = last_name
    End Sub
End Class
```

copy to clipboard:

```
Private Sub btnCopy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCopy.Click
        Dim emp As New Employee(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text)
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(emp)
    End Sub
```

and paste

```
Private Sub btnPaste_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnPaste.Click
    Dim data_object As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject
    If data_object.GetDataPresent("howto_net_clipboard_object.Employee") Then
        Dim emp As Employee = DirectCast(data_object.GetData("howto_net_clipboard_object.Employee"), Employee)
        txtDropFirstName.Text = emp.FirstName
        txtDropLastName.Text = emp.LastName
    Else
        txtDropFirstName.Text = ""
        txtDropLastName.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Test 1 - after VS Community 2019 converted the source - run the program - works.

Test 2 - copied the converted source - copy in one prog and paste in the other - works.

Test 3 - Opened VS with a new project, build the same form layout and copied the code and ran my new version and the original. This time a received the same error as in my application.

What do I miss?

Comment: You can use the [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer) class to serialize/deserialize your class object(s) to a MemoryStream, then set the `[MemoryStream].ToArray()` as the content object of `ClipBoard.SetData()`. Use the overload that allows to specify a custom Format. On the other side, cast the object to `byte()` and use it to rebuild a MemoryStream that is passed to the XmlSerializer, along with the `Type` (your Employee class type - as `GetType(Employee)`), for deserialization.

Comment: Thanks Jimi for the reply but that is not an answer it's a bypass that might lead to more trouble. I have tested another bypass, writing the data to temp file and transferring thru  the clipboard as file drop. I test this on the two test programs and it works in all direction.

Comment: A *bypass*? What does that event mean? You cannot copy to a ClipBoard a cross-domain object. You only get an empty MemoryStream. You have to serialize the class object. BinaryFormatter, without assembly references, is relatively complex, while `XmlSerializer` is extremely simple (you need 4 lines of code for everyting). If you want to call something a *bypass*, that would be using the ClipBoard for data communication purposes, instead of WCF, NamedPipes, AnonymousPipes, NamedPipeServerStream/NamedPipeClientStream etc.

Comment: Please refer to my original post - test 2, this where two programs that didn't use  XmlSerializer only <Serializable()> and it worked.

Comment: Yes, well your description of the operations performed is not that clear. If you want, I can show you how to communicate between two running applications using Named Pipes, so you won't disrupt the ClipBoard used by other applications (and yours, maybe).

Comment: I have continued investigating and found out that if both programs have the same assembly name and root namespace you can transfer object between the programs. However when you change one of the names the program crashes. May be this will help you find an answer for the question.

Comment: The answer is already in the 3 comments I left here. One of the main points is *don't use the ClipBoard for cross-process/cross-domain data exchange*. If you have to (for unknown reasons), then serialize the data.